# Permission problems accessing android camera

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-camera

I'm very newbie in this Android world, and I'm trying to build an app to record video and GPS information.

I'm facing some issues to access the camera. No errors, but it seems permission was not granted.

Manifest: I think there are many redundant lines, but I was trying all possibilities.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERAX" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERAX" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Starting Camera:

```
  @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private void cameraXStart(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        // Image capture use case
        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .build();

        // Video capture use case
        videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
                .setVideoFrameRate(30)
                .build();

        //bind to lifecycle:
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, videoCapture);

    }
```

Then, I have this one to allow camera usage:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 100);
```

When I run, I get thisL

> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Cancelling scheduled re-open: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@5296b52
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Opening camera.
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: REOPENING --> OPENING
> D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
> D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-f0c976a1-2b26-4655-88d6-6790eae98eb6206680605, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-c788dcee-3839-4ff7-ad80-908046a7a19e41671826, androidx.camera.core.Preview-45eb99ce-6730-444c-a6dc-e4baabab208b69765876] for camera: 0
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Unable to open camera due to validateClientPermissionsLocked:913: Caller "com.example.trucklogger" (PID 10105, UID 5516) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> REOPENING
> D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Attempting camera re-open in 1000ms: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@a4eea9e activeResuming = true
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Attempting to force open the camera.
> D/CameraStateRegistry: tryOpenCamera(Camera@721ce9d[id=0]) [Available Cameras: 0, Already Open: true (Previous state: OPENING)] --> SUCCESS
> D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
> Camera                                       State
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Camera@dd4530c[id=1]                         UNKNOWN
> Camera@721ce9d[id=0]                         OPENING
> Camera@3be637[id=2]                          UNKNOWN
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Cancelling scheduled re-open: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@a4eea9e
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Opening camera.
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: REOPENING --> OPENING
> D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
> D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-f0c976a1-2b26-4655-88d6-6790eae98eb6206680605, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-c788dcee-3839-4ff7-ad80-908046a7a19e41671826, androidx.camera.core.Preview-45eb99ce-6730-444c-a6dc-e4baabab208b69765876] for camera: 0
> **D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Unable to open camera due to validateClientPermissionsLocked:913: Caller "com.example.trucklogger" (PID 10105, UID 5516) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission**
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> REOPENING
> D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
> D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@721ce9d[id=0]} Attempting camera re-open in 1000ms: androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback$ScheduledReopen@4421195 activeResuming = true

**Any idea how could I fix it?!
Thank you <3**

Comment: Try this code in manifest file above application tag
**<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>**
and remove the unnecessary permissions... it may create some conflict sometimes !!

Comment: Thank you my friend. I'm sorry, but also didn't work. 
I checked the permission on settings, and couldn't find CAMERA on the list. It is supposed to be there, isn't it?!?

Comment: You can give a try by adding this to your manifest **`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`** or you can add this **`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  android:required"true"/>`**

Comment: Still not working. I have no idea why. Also, if I try to enter from the phone it doesn't show any camera perdition.